# UPDATE a column based on the value of another column in the same table

Tags: mysql

UPDATE a column REGNO based on the value of another column SERIAL and YEAR_ADMITTED in the same table.

```
SERIAL | REGNO | YEAR_ADMITTED | FULL_NAME
---------------------------------------------
0001   |       |  2011         | LUM Anye
1009   |       |  2014         | Hans Musah
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You can reference other fields in the same row in the `SET` and `WHERE` clause in an `UPDATE` statement, if you didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

As per Fabricator's suggestion amended to include a where clause so you don't overwrite and existing REGNO.

```
UPDATE students SET REGNO = CONCAT( year_admitted, SERIAL )
WHERE REGNO IS NULL OR REGNO=''
```

You may have to `CAST` year_admitted if it is not already a string

```
UPDATE students SET REGNO = CONCAT( CAST(year_admitted as CHAR), SERIAL )
WHERE REGNO IS NULL OR REGNO=''
```

Comment: You are right, CAST it as YEAR(year_admitted). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `students` SET `REGNO` = ( SELECT CONCAT( YEAR( `year_admitted` ) , `SERIAL` ) )
WHERE SERIAL = SERIAL
```

Comment: how about `UPDATE students SET REGNO = CONCAT( YEAR( year_admitted ) , SERIAL )`

Comment: `WHERE SERIAL = SERIAL` does nothing whatsoever.  Are you entering a variable there?

Comment: Thank you Frabricator and @Rocket Hazmat