# Update a date column with the result of the next closest date column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| person_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| location_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| date_signed | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date_ended  | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Where all of the records are like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| person_id | location_id | date_signed | date_ended |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|         1 |          49 | 2007-09-29  | NULL       |
|         1 |          41 | 2010-10-09  | NULL       |
|         2 |          45 | 2007-09-29  | NULL       |
|         2 |          58 | 2007-12-16  | NULL       |
|         3 |          49 | 2007-09-29  | NULL       |
|         4 |          45 | 2007-09-29  | NULL       |
|         4 |          35 | 2013-10-04  | NULL       |
|         5 |          45 | 2007-09-29  | NULL       |
|         5 |          37 | 2009-01-09  | NULL       |
|         5 |          32 | 2009-10-08  | NULL       |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to update each person's `date_ended` to be one day less than the `date_signed` in the next chronological row for that person:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| person_id | location_id | date_signed | date_ended |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|         1 |          49 | 2007-09-29  | 2010-10-08 |
|         1 |          41 | 2010-10-09  | NULL       |
|         2 |          45 | 2007-09-29  | 2007-12-15 |
|         2 |          58 | 2007-12-16  | NULL       |
.
.
.
```

But I can't figure out how to select the next chronological record. I tried a few suggestions from similar questions:

[UPDATE a column based on the value of another column in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033662/update-a-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-column-in-the-same-table)

[Mysql - update table column from another column based on order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384484/mysql-update-table-column-from-another-column-based-on-order)

[ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

But I couldn't get them to work. Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b5219/1

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Added a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the progress report